# How to prevent lack of potassium from physical activity?

Tags: nutrition, prevention, treatment-options, minerals

My question is based on my (quite) recent experience.

I have ridden on my bicycle since September of 2012. This activity leads to decreasing of volume of kalium (potassium). Hard to say how much.

Some types of fruit contain potassium. And I eat fruit.

But what *food additives* should I use to keep potassium at reasonable levels?

Comment: Please do not answer in comments. They are intended to clarify and refine questions/answers.

Comment: @Lucky: I used _scientific_ name of this element, because it is clear, and not confusing with names of chemicals in else languages.

Comment: Actually, if you view edit history (just click on the blue edit date) you'll see that I've only accepted the edit of kalium to potassium. In science written in English, "potassium" is an accepted term. What's more, most users of health SE are not the people of science. All questions and answers posted here should serve future users; in order to achieve that it is better if names of elements that are understandable to many people are used. This is why I've accepted the edit. I hope you understand :-)